# componentsSeparatedByString returns nil for array

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have an issue like, when I try to seperate string and fetching array from the same usingcomponentsSeparatedByString , the stringis having values but when it provides values to array , the array value is always null, please help me, I have attached code below.

```
    self.str_amenitiesValues = [[NSString alloc] init];
    self.str_amenitiesValues = [[arr_HotspotDetails valueForKey:@"Amenities"] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.arr_amenities_values =[[NSArray alloc] init];

    if (![self.str_amenitiesValues isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {
        //NSLog(@"%@",[self.str_amenitiesValues componentsSeparatedByString:@","]);   
        self.arr_amenities_values = [self.str_amenitiesValues componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    }
```

Comment: what is in arr_HotspotDetails? And what is in self.str_amenitiesValues just before the componentsSeparatedByString?

Comment: arr_hotspotDetails is the main array from where the string is coming, and str_amenitiesValues is the nsstring ,

Comment: I see that they are array and string. I want to know what is IN it

Comment: str_amenitiesvalues is 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 and arr_amenitues_values , array which will receive the values from the str_amenitiesvalues.

Comment: @iPhoneFun: I think there is some typing mistake or else you are not properly understanding the coding in objective C. What is importance of `self.str_amenitiesValues = [[NSString alloc] init];` if any way you are assigning value to same string from `[[arr_HotspotDetails valueForKey:@"Amenities"] objectAtIndex:0];`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make ur line as:

```
self.arr_amenities_values = [[self.str_amenitiesValues componentsSeparatedByString:@","] retain];
```

let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Comment your line where memory is being allocated to your array and then check with above line.

Comment: if you have to add `retain` to a value that is set by its synthesized setter you have a bug somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure that str_amenitiesvalues is "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"? I just did a quick test and that's what I got:

```
NSString *test = @"5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12";
NSArray *testArray = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"test: %@ \n testArray: %@", test, testArray);
```

Log output:

```
test: 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 
testArray: (
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12
)
```

So I'd recommend you double checking the content of your string str_amenitiesvalues

Comment: and the only way `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns nil is if the receiver NSString is nil.

Comment: btw, I removed a memory leak from your code. There is no need to alloc/init an array if you overwrite it in the next line.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch ok, thank you. But I just tried to keep it as close to the question code as possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the values of all your vars at different stages so you can figure out what's happening, as there doesn't appear to be any reason it won't work, other than the contents of the string.

Comment: values if str_amenitiesvalues is 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting the string to nil, as Matthias Bauch suggests? componentsSeparatedByString WILL work on the string you've provided!